# Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect_errno() in

Tags: php, html, mysql

code is save in two file 1 is html and 2 is php file
i am new in php please help

I am receiving the following error message:

Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect_errno() in C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\saveCode.php on line 11

I want to save couple of fields in a database

please provode any solution

**HTML code**

```
<BODY>

<form method="post" action="saveCode.php">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>

<TEXTAREA name="txtEn" onkeypress=writeurdu(event); id="id" dir=lft NAME="id" 
                style="font-size:xx-large;" rows="1"></TEXTAREA></td>
        <td>
<!--<TEXTAREA id="urd" dir=rtl NAME="id" ROWS="1" COLS="40"></TEXTAREA style="font-size:xx-large;">-->

<TEXTAREA name="txtAr" id="urd" style=" width:388px; height:141px; border:solid 1px green;font-size:xx-large;" 
                dir=rtl align="center"></TEXTAREA></td>
<div  ></div>
</td>



    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Persio Arabic
</td>
        <td>
            Roman
</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            &nbsp;</td>
        <td>

    <textarea name="comments">Example Comment</textarea>
    <input name="submitSave" type="submit" value="Save" />
        </form>
           <a href="" id="btn_Save" name="lnkSave"> Save</a>
            <input type="button" id="btn_View" value="View" /> </td>
    </tr>
</table>

</form>




</BODY>
```

**SaveCode.php**

```
   <?php

     $conn_error='Could not Connect';
      $mysql_host='localhost';
      $mysql_user='root';
      $mysql_pass='';
      $mysql_db='db_ZS';

    $con=mysql_connect($mysql_host,$mysql_user,$mysql_pass,$mysql_db);

    if (mysql_connect_errno())
      {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_connect_error();
      }

    mysql_query($con,"INSERT INTO tlb1 (EN,AR) values ({$_POST['txtAr']},{$_POST['txtEn']})");

    mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Syntax highlighting gives the error away. If you use a decent IDE or text editor you should be able to spot this quickly.

Comment: Close your quote on the query string

Comment: which text editor i should use Name any1

Comment: Komodo Edit isn't bad.

Answer (score 3):

There is [no function called mysql_connect_errno](https://www.php.net/manual-lookup.php?pattern=mysql_connect_errno&scope=quickref) in PHP, but there is `mysqli_connect_errno`.  You need to make sure you're using all mysqli_ functions though, you cannot mix mysql and mysqli functions.

Answer (score 0):

As the syntax colouring on here shows, you're missing a closing quote. It should be:

```
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO tlb1 (EN,AR) values ({$_POST['txtAr']},{$_POST['txtEn']})");
```

It may be an idea to use an IDE / text editor with syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistake in your code, you didn't close double quote. Please change

```
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO tlb1 (EN,AR) values ({$_POST['txtAr']},{$_POST['txtEn']}));
```

To

```
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO tlb1 (EN,AR) values ({$_POST['txtAr']},{$_POST['txtEn']})");
```