# No output with echo using php

Tags: php, database, insert

I've the following code to insert in my mysql database on my webserver:

```
<?php 
$connect = mysql_connect("server", "user", "pwd"); 
$database = "dbname"; 
@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to seleact database"); 
echo 'test1'; 

if(mysql_connect_errno($connect)) 
{ 
echo 'test2'; 
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_connect_error(); 
} 

else 
{ 
echo 'test3'; 

} 

$name= isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : ''; 
$email= isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : ''; 
echo 'hallo' . $name; 
$query = mysql_query($connect, "insert into jagdenwilli(name, email) values ('$name' ,'$email') "); 
mysql_close($connect); 

?>
```

The problem is, that after 'test1' there is no output anymore. Also the writing to the database still not working. Does someone see my error?

Comment: Use mysqli. any errors you got?

Comment: I love how you suppress all errors and warnings in the third line and then complain about undefined behaviour occurring. The real problem of course is that [`mysql_connect_errno` is not a valid function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16002486/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-mysql-connect-errno-in).

Comment: There is no such method `mysql_connect_errno`. Since you have errors turned off no output is produced to tell you function not found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    The only problem with the previous code is syntax error.


    Try these one with connection update :


      <?php 

           $connect = mysql_connect("server", "user", "pwd"); 
           $database = "dbname"; 

           if(! $connect )
             {
               die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
             }

           echo 'Connected successfully';            

           mysql_select_db($database);

           echo 'test1'; 

           $name= isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : ''; 
           $email= isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : ''; 

           echo 'hallo' . $name; 

           $query = mysql_query( "INSERT INTO jagdenwilli(name, email) 
                                  VALUES ('$name','$email') "); 


           mysql_close($connect);


       ?>
```

Comment: @user896692 : was that best answer you selected? what would be happen if you have not connected to the database? there are no check for database connection error here!

Comment: @user896692 Thank u for remind me I just updated the code with connection checking.

Answer (score 2):

Bonus tips:
**You should always see your server error log first. You will definitely get some clue from there**
Try this:

```
<?php 
    $connect = mysql_connect("server", "user", "pwd"); 
    $database = "dbname"; 
    @mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to seleact database"); 
    echo 'test1'; 

    if(!$connect) 
    { 
    echo 'test2'; 
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " .mysql_error(); 
    } 

    else 
    { 
    echo 'test3'; 

    } 

    $name= isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : ''; 
    $email= isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : ''; 
    echo 'hallo' . $name; 
    $query = mysql_query($connect, "insert into jagdenwilli(name, email) values ('$name' ,'$email') "); 
    mysql_close($connect); 

?>
```

Comment: @user896692 : see your server error log you should see undefined method  mysql_connect_errno. Now it should work.

Answer (score 1):

there is no function mysql_connect_errno() in php there is one mysqli_connect_errno for mysqli

Answer (score 1):

There is no function mysql_connect_errno().

You can check `if(!$connect)` to determine whether the connection succeed or not, instead.